How to Replace Deprecated queryForObject in Spring JDBC Template Without Code Smell?
I'm using Spring JDBC Template in my application, and I've noticed that the queryForObject method I'm using is deprecated. I want to update my code to avoid any potential issues and eliminate code smells.
Here's the current implementation of my validateOTP method:
@Override
public boolean validateOTP(OTPValidateDTO otpValidateDTO) {
    try {
        var sql ="SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM otp_table WHERE otp = ? AND mobile_no = ?);";
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,
                new Object[]{otpValidateDTO.getOtp(), otpValidateDTO.getMobileNo()},
                Boolean.class));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}


I looked into using **queryForObject **with **PreparedStatement **and ResultSetExtractor, but it seemed overly complicated for my use case.
I considered using queryForList and then checking if the list is empty, but that felt like a hack.

What is the recommended way to replace **queryForObject **in this context to avoid deprecation and maintain clean, efficient code?

Now if only there would be one quite similar but with varargs like a queryForObject(sql, class, varargs)... O wait, there is -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.37/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcOperations.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...- Before coming here to ask a question I would suggest looking at the API and the documentation (the deprecated method even linked to the varargs one).

I would not return false on exception. Instead I would throw the exception from the method.
